# R, class() returns different results for data frame columns

Tags: r

```
> bb = data.frame(x = c( 11:13), y = c(1:3), z = c("a", "a", "b"))
> bb
   x y z
1 11 1 a
2 12 2 a
3 13 3 b
> 
> apply( bb, 2, class)
          x           y           z 
"character" "character" "character" 
>
> apply( bb[,1:2], 2, class)
        x         y 
"integer" "integer" 
>    
> apply( bb[,2:3], 2, class)
          y           z 
"character" "character" 
> 
> class(bb$z)
[1] "factor"
>
```

I was quite surprised to find class() behavior illustrated above.Could someone please give any rationale for above inconsistencies. Many thanks.

Comment: Please read `?apply`: "If `X` is [...] a data frame), `apply` attempts to coerce it to an array via `as.matrix`". Then keep on reading `?as.matrix`: "The method for data frames will return a character matrix if there is only atomic columns and **any non-(numeric/logical/complex) column**, [...] Otherwise, the usual coercion hierarchy (logical < integer < double < complex) will be used"

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that `apply` converts everything to `character` class as it converts it to `matrix` and `matrix` can hold only a single class  i.e. if there is at least one column is  non-numeric, the entire dataset gets changed to `character`.  Instead, we could use,

```
lapply(bb, class)
#$x
#[1] "integer"

#$y
#[1] "integer"

#$z
#[1] "factor"
```

The above returns the output in a `list`.  If we need it as a `vector`, use `sapply`

```
sapply(bb, class)
```

or

```
vapply(bb, class, '')
```

You can alternatively use `str()` to inspect your data frame

```
str(bb)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
#  $ x: int  11 12 13
#  $ y: int  1 2 3
#  $ z: Factor w/ 2 levels "a","b": 1 1 2
```

As the OP showed in the post that whenever it was only numeric columns, the correct class was displayed with `apply` until a non-numeric column was added into the mix.